# How to move CALayer with UIScrollView together?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I created a UIScrollView, and also a CALayer on top of it.

My question is when I scroll the view, how CALayer can also moves?

For example the CALayer is always at the relative position of the UIScrollView when the UIScrollView moves or zoom get changed.